# Store Thumbnails in Redis

Tags: amazon-s3, redis, thumbnails

For a messenger app I store the latest messages in Redis.

They will be kept for 24 hours. Along with each message I have a thumbnail image.

Is it a good approach to store the thumbnail (2KB each) along with the message in Redis? It would make fetching the messages much faster since I get the message and the image in one transaction.

Or should the thumbnail be stored in S3 despite the fact that I need an additional PUT and GET request per message?

**Edit:**

The thumbnails are different per message. A message consists out of a text and a link to an image. While the full resolution image is stored on S3, the message saved in Redis contains only a link to it.

The client is an iOS app. The app collects all messages from Redis. If the message contains an image, only the thumbnail should be shown before downloading the full resolution file.

The application design must allow thousands of requests / second.

See WhatsApp example:

[image]

**Edit:**

I calculated the AWS cost for both options.

**Redis:** Redis would cost 3k USD for 120 Million messages.

**S3:** An additional PUT request per message would double the S3 costs. 10k USD for 1B messages / month

Comment: Is the thumbnail really different for every message?  It's hard to say w/o knowing your app; most messenger apps I know would have a thumbnail per user or something similar.  In any case, you don't provide enough info here to judge "better" with any degree of objectivity. What's the client for this info? Web, mobile, other?  How often to the actual thumbnail images change?  What are your performance constraints? What processing (if any) happens on the images?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question

Comment: could you explain more on message thumbnail? I could not picture what do you mean by the thumbnail of a message. Is it the thumbnail of an image message, or even the text message could have a thumbnail? If you could give some examples messages, that would be great for us to understand :)

Comment: also, it would be good if you could give us some insights on your load specs, like average concurrent user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume this is your requirement:

- An iOS app instant messaging app;
- There will be **1k/s** messages;
- If the message contains preview-able information, like video/img, a thumbnail should be displayed.

Some inferred conditions:

- There might be **3k/s** messages during peak;
- There might be **3k/s** preview-able messages during peak.

I assume the other part of your system is well-done, and won't have bottle neck. 1k/s messages means you need to do at least 1k write per second to redis, that's totally nothing to redis. Then you are asking if you need to store the thumbnail of preview-able information as well in the redis, and my quick and personal answer is **NO**.

#### Client Aspect

First question you should ask yourself is, does respond time really matter for client in this case? Would the missing of the preview be a big trouble and cause a major user experience degradation? Are there any ways to bear with slow respond time while maintaining a relatively high UX?

I believe users won't be too unhappy if he/she didn't see a preview of a video/img, compared to missing the video/img link. I agree that missing an img preview may cause some UX degradation, but why you would display it something saying "I'm bad please blame me"? You could display the img whenever you received the full thumbnail.

#### Server Aspect

First question you should ask is, does caching give any more benefit than uploading? Besides, does caching introduce any problems?

Since you might not have good control on the thumbnail size, **pushing to redis might take longer and consume more resource than you expected.** And this may cause some issues on writing text messages into redis. Also, if you store the thumbnail in redis, you need to require the thumbnail through your server, which is one more request, and a big response.

#### Suggestions

Don't store in redis, just generate the thumbnail and upload to S3. Trust amazon, they are good, for most of the time.

But wait, are we done? Absolutely no. Why we need to upload the image to our server first, then asks the server to generate thumbnail upload them? Why can't we just do it on the client side?

Yes, that's another solution. Compress the picture, upload thumbnail and full size to S3, and get a link to it, and send the link to server. Then the server will send this link to the other client, and the other client will fetch the image from S3.

In this way, your server won't be flooded by huge images, even during peak.

#### Concerns

There are of course quite a lot concerns: how to handle upload failure case? How to handle malicious abusing actions? How to handle duplicated images (like stickers)? How to link an image with a chat room?

I will leave these questions to you, since some of them are biz logic related :)

#### Last Words

**DO do load test and benchmark using good simulation of traffic and good logging** so that you know where's the bottle neck, and could optimize wisely.

And always remember: Get it run first, then get it right, and get it fast only if you have enough motivation and strong reason. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), and, a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Talking to someone else really helps a lot. I even figured out that I can store the thumbnail along with the full resolution image in one merged file. To download the thumbnail I would then only request the first 2KB from S3 (which would be the thumbnail). This would save me the additional PUT request per message ... (But maybe that's already over optimization)

Comment: @ nevets I was able to append the thumbnail to the full resolution file. This allows to have only one PUT request per message. To receive the thumbnail I request only the last 10KB from the full resolution image and search where the thumbnail beginns (putting the thumbnail at the end of the file allows to view the full resolution without any further processing). Is this a common approach?

Comment: @user3211074 i edited my answer to include some of my thoughts on implementing a chat :p And my personal opinion is, get it run first, then get it right, and get it fast as `TODO` :p